# Spring xd module design

Tags: spring-xd

1. I have a spring xd source module which is rabbit-mq and I have a
   processor1 to  transform the input.
2. The message then gets passed to http-client  and http client will
   call a external webservice.
3. From http client my message will go to processor2  and it will
   invoke

rabbitsource | processor1 | http-client1 | processor2 | http-client2 |
mongo sink

Now  the doubt is I want to pass some data from processor 1 to  processor 2 How can i do it ?My processor2 will use some data from processor1 and  response returned from http-client1 .How can I pass a message from processor 1 to processor 2.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add one or more message headers in processor1 or add a header-enricher module after processor1 and the headers will be available to processor2.